# What is the shortest NOOP statement for setting breakpoint?

Tags: java

What is the simplest, shortest, and easiest to write NOOP statement to set a breakpoint upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line requires least keystrokes (8 keystrokes) ...

```
int j=0;
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because is smaller than others statements.

Answer (score 2):

<s>if(true);</s>

or

```
if(false);
```

note the semicolon after the if which makes it self-contained

edit: `while(true)break;` does work for creating a breakpoint

Comment: It is short, but unfortunately it cannot be triggered by breakpoint. JDK 1.6 + Eclipse 3.7

Comment: Simple, elegant, but wrong! There is no bytecode generated for either case, so a breakpoint can't be set on such statement...

Comment: @HowardGuo made a better version that does work on my eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can make an obvious assertion to set a breakpoint :

```java
assert Boolean.TRUE; //Set your breakpoint here
```

Or you can create a noop() method somewhere for this purpose :

```java
noop(); //Set your breakpoint here

...

public void noop(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
boolean breakhere = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
byte _breakpoint_ = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a new named variable, I usually just use

```
"".isEmpty();
```

It may require more keystrokes to type it fully, but by using IDE auto-complete, I can usually do it in only 5-6 keystrokes.